# Quartic Pell's equation - solving

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

We are all aware of the fact that the equation $a^2-Nb^2=1$ ($N\in\mathbb{N_{\ge 0}}$, $N\neq k^2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$) has infinitely many solutions such that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. But what about such equation as $a^{\color{red}4}-Nb^{\color{red}4}=1$. Can we also find infinitely many solutions to such equation (such that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$)?

Answer (score 2):

Such an equation has only finitely many integer solutions.
This is a special case of a classical (but still hard)
1909 theorem of Thue.  See Wikipedia's article on
[Thue equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue_equation)
for further information.